How to run cucumber feature file in intellij idea to see each step in run window
Right now, when I run a feature file in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.0.1 (Ultimate Edition)(with the Cucumber plugin enabled) it runs as a gradle task with logs in the console as in the usual gradle task:

some time ago I remember it showed a nice UI to the left with each step \ feature separated in its line with its logs to the right if selected.
How do I enable it back?

As always with IntelliJ, a lot of regression bugs appear with each new release. Did you try version 2024.2.0.2?

@OrtomalaLokni Yes, I tried it but result is the same

This is a known bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2 where Cucumber steps are incorrectly shown as plain text instead of being recognized as Cucumber steps. You can track the issue and any updates with IDEA-357578.
This bug is not present in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.
== Update 9 October 2024==
This should be fixed in 2024.2.4. See : IDEA-356996 : Running Cucumber tests with Gradle shows steps as plain text

Yeah, I guess that is the issue with the Intellij Idea version. I've tried to run Cucumber scenarios on 2023.3.7 and scenarios and steps displayed as expected.
So I guess we will have to wait for JetBrains to fix this
